# How to post the result of a sql query into a servlet?

Tags: java, sql, servlets

I keep getting stuck on this.

Here is my servlet:

```
package HWpackage;

import java.io.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class DemoData extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Demo of Data Persistence</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

        try {
              String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
              String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@coit-ora01.uncc.edu:1521:class";
              String username = "johnR";
              String password = "lAylko0K";

              // Load database driver if it's not already loaded.
              Class.forName(driver);
              // Establish network connection to database.
              Connection connection =
                DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
              // Create a statement for executing queries.
              Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
              String query =
                "SELECT sum(cost) FROM stocks where username = 'Bora'";
              // Send query to database and store results.
              ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

              while(resultSet.next()) {


                out.println("Your total cost is" );


              }
              connection.close();
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
              System.err.println("Error loading driver: " + cnfe);
              // Useful when you debug your program on the coit server
              // where System.out.println("") becomes futile
              out.println("<tr>  Error loading driver: " + cnfe);
              out.println("</tr>");
            } catch(SQLException sqle) {
              System.err.println("Error with connection: " + sqle);
              // Again, for debug purpose
              out.println("<tr>  Error with connection: " + sqle);
              out.println("</tr>");
            }

            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally { 
            out.close();
        }
    } 

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } 

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** 
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */

    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

I'd like to know the correct way to post the result of this query in the servlet:

```
String query =
                "SELECT sum(cost) FROM stocks where username = 'Bora'";
```

after the is

```
out.println("Your total cost is" );
```

If someone could provide me that information you will seriously make my night.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, can you elaborate please? And what do you mean 'post the result of SQL query into servlet'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways is to do this:-

1. `SELECT sum(cost) AS COST FROM stocks where username = 'Bora'`
2. In this code block modify to:

> while(resultSet.next()) {
>
> ```
>             Double cost = resultSet.getDouble("COST");   
>             out.println("Your total cost is" + cost );
> ```
>
> }

**Side notes:**

1. Do not hard code sql parameters this way. You are prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Use parameter markers ie. `` `SELECT sum(cost) AS COST FROM stocks where username = ? `` and JDBC [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to execute it.
2. Create a separate [DAO](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) class for handing all database work. This will promote decoupling in your code.

Comment: Here is an additional question...I set up a DAO but I'm stuck at trying to figure out how I pull the ResultSet from the DAO into another servlet.  How would I call that ResultSet and set it as a String?

Comment: You dont call a resultset, you invoke your DAO method. The DAO method will determine how to execute the query and return the data back as a string or a double or whatever applies.

Answer (score 0):

```
out.println("Your total cost is "+resultSet.getString("sum(cost)"));
```